# Cachetools for subsequent runs in python

Tags: python, caching

Am a beginner.Sorry if my question is childish . Do cachetools in python work for susbsequent runs?

```
import cachetools
import time


@cachetools.cached({})
def find_sum(n):
    time.sleep(5)
    return n+2


print find_sum(2)
print find_sum(3)
print find_sum(2)
```

So during the first run the third call is faster but the next time i run the file i want the first call to be faster and take result from the cache. Can cachetools do this?

Answer (score 14):

[`cachetools`](http://cachetools.readthedocs.io/) cannot do this out of the box. But it's very easy to add.

You can pass any mutable mapping you want to the [memoizing decorators](http://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#memoizing-decorators). You're using a plain old dict, and dicts are trivial to pickle. And even if you use one of the fancy [cache implementations](http://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cache-implementations) provided by the library, they're all easy to pickle as well.<sup>1</sup>

So:

```
import cachetools
import pickle
import time

try:
    with open('mycache.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        cache = pickle.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    cache = {} # or cachetools.LRUCache(maxsize=5) or whatever you want

@cachetools.cached(cache)
def find_sum(n):
    time.sleep(5)
    return n+2

print(find_sum(2))
print(find_sum(3))
print(find_sum(2))

with open('mycache.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(cache, f)
```

---

Of course you can add:

- A `finally` or context manager or `atexit` to make sure you save your files at shutdown even if you hit an exception or ^C.
- A timer that saves them every so often.
- A hook on the cache object to save on every update, or every Nth update. (Just override the `__setitem__` method—or see [Extending cache classes](http://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#extending-cache-classes) for other things you can do, if you use one of the fancier classes instead of a dict.)

---

Or you can even use an on-disk key-value database as a cache.

The simplest such database is [`dbm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html). It's limited to `str`/`bytes` for both keys and values. (You can use [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) if you want non-string values; if you want non-string keys, you probably want a different solution.) So, that doesn't quite work for our example. But for a similar example, it's almost magic:

```
import dbm
import time
import cachetools

cache = dbm.open('mycache.dbm', 'c')
@cachetools.cached(cache, key=lambda s:s)
def find_string_sum(s):
    time.sleep(5)
    return s + '!'

print(find_string_sum('a'))
print(find_string_sum('b'))
print(find_string_sum('a'))
```

The only tricky bit was that I had to override the `key` function. (The default key function handles `*args, **kw`, so for argument `'a'` you end up with something like `(('a',), ())`, which is obviously not a string.)

---

<sub>1. As you can see from [the source](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools/blob/master/cachetools/rr.py#L8), there are bug fixes to make sure all of the classes are picklable in all supported Python versions, so this is clearly intentional.</sub>

Comment: This fails for me, I've raised an issue with cachetools but the hash of the cache keys isn't invariant to pickle load / dump for some reason.

Comment: The issue with the hash key is probably resolved: https://github.com/tkem/cachetools/issues/130, otherwise use a custom key `@cachetools.cached(cache=cache,key=lambda n: n)`